# ImportError django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I decided to run new project with similar content, it worked fine until I added

```
from hotel_auth import test

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('test/'), test,
]
```

into urls.py. The first row where I import underline in IDEA with "Unresolved reference 'hotel_auth'"

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'hotel_auth',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'hotel_booking.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 
        'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'hotel_booking.wsgi.application'
```

hotel_auth views

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def test(request):
context = {
    'tittle': 'some tittle',
    'description': 'descr'
}
return JsonResponse(context)
```

error i get

[image: error log]

Comment: `from django.contrib.HotelAuth.views import test` causes the Error. Your `HotelAuth.views` module lives in some local package, certainly not in `django.contrib.auth`.

Comment: Please copy and paste the traceback instead of posting screenshots.

Comment: You had correct code in your previous version: `from hotel_auth import test` and `path('test/', test),` and replaced it with incorrect code `from hotel_auth import test` and `path('test/'), test,`. It's not fair to completely re-write your question again and again - it means that old answers don't make sense any more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
    'django.contrib.auth',
```

into INSTALLED_APPS insteed of 'django.contrib.HotelAuth', and probably you also miss

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

in django settings.